# Struggling with Custom Client Validation in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, client-side-validation

I am not sure if I am going to phrase this correctly or not.  I know what I want the program to do, but not how to go about it.  I am trying to validate checkboxes on the page before it goes to the server.  So I want the client validation to tell it if there is an error.
     I am going to post a section of the view that is displayed, as the rest of it is the same.  Here is the output from the web browser:

```
<tr>
   <td class="hidden">1</td>
   <td class="hidden">1</td>
   <td>Ale Association</td>
   <td class="col-md-1"><input name="FactionSet" class="toggle" id="FactionSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The FactionSet field is required." data-val="true"></td>
   <td>
     <div class="form-group" id="newGrid">
       <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="mvc-grid" id="Grid">
           <table class="table">
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th class=" hidden"><span class="mvc-grid-header-title"></span></th>
                 <th><span class="mvc-grid-header-title"></span></th>
                 <th><span class="mvc-grid-header-title"></span></th>
                 <th class=" hidden"><span class="mvc-grid-header-title"></span></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="hidden">6</td>
                <td><input name="ReputationIsChecked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" data-val-required="The ReputationIsChecked field is required." data-val="true"></td>
                <td>Enemy</td>
                <td class="hidden">0</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td class="hidden">13</td>
               <td><input name="ReputationIsChecked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true"></td>
               <td>Neutral</td>
               <td class="hidden">1</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td class="hidden">1</td>
               <td><input name="ReputationIsChecked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true"></td>
               <td>Acquaintance</td>
               <td class="hidden">2</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td class="hidden">8</td>
               <td><input name="ReputationIsChecked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true"></td>
               <td>Friend</td>
               <td class="hidden">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="hidden">2</td>
              <td><input name="ReputationIsChecked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true"></td>
              <td>Ally</td>
              <td class="hidden">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="hidden">11</td>
              <td><input name="ReputationIsChecked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true"></td>
              <td>Kindred</td>
              <td class="hidden">5</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td></tr>
```

So what I am looking at is that I need to error out any of the ReputationIsChecked checkboxes if the FactionSet checkbox is not checked.  I also need to error out if a checkbox is checked and the preceding ReputationIsChecked is unchecked.

Currently I have induced errors that are passing validation on the page, and I am unable to find a way to make the client side validation work.  The JQuery validation scripts are included in the _Layout for the page, but do not seem to be working.  I am going to pass along the Models, and the Views that create this.  Maybe someone knows the trick to get this to work.

CharacterReputationListViewModel

```
public class CharacterReputationListViewModel
{
    public CharacterReputationListViewModel()
    {
        this.CharacterCharID = CharacterCharID;
        this.FactionFactionID = FactionFactionID;
        this.FactionName = FactionName;
        this.FactionSet = FactionSet;
        this.ReputationLevelID = ReputationLevelID;
        this.RepLevels = new List<ReputationLevelListViewModel>();
    }
    public int CharacterCharID { get; set; }
    public int FactionFactionID { get; set; }
    public string FactionName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The previous value must be selected")]
    public bool FactionSet { get; set; }
    public int ReputationLevelID { get; set; }
    public List<ReputationLevelListViewModel> RepLevels { get; set; }

}
```

ReputationLevelListViewModel

```
public class ReputationLevelListViewModel
{
    public int FactionID { get; set; }
    public int ReputationLevelID { get; set; }
    public string ReputationLevelName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The previous value must be selected")]
    public bool ReputationIsChecked { get; set; }
    public int ReputationLevelTier { get; set; }
}
```

Edit.cshtml

```
<form asp-controller="CharacterReputations" asp-action="Edit" method="post">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Character Reputation</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <b style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size: x-large">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name.CharacterFullName)</b>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Reputation" class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
        @Html.Partial("_RepEditPartial", @Model.Reputation)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => Model.Reputation.Select(b => b.FactionSet), "", new { @class = "validation_error" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div></form>
```

_RepEditPartial.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
    @(Html
        .Grid(Model)
        .Build(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add(model => model.CharacterCharID).Css("hidden");
            columns.Add(model => model.FactionFactionID).Css("hidden");
            columns.Add(model => model.FactionName).Titled("Faction");
            columns.Add(model => model.FactionSet).Titled("Available").Encoded(false).RenderedAs(model => Html.CheckBoxFor(a => model.FactionSet, new { @class="toggle"})).Css("col-md-1");
            columns.Add(model => model.RepLevels).Titled("Reputation").Encoded(false).RenderedAs(model => Html.Partial("_RepLevelEditPartial", model.RepLevels));

        })
        .Pageable(pager =>
        {
            pager.RowsPerPage = 25;
        })
        .Empty("No Data Found")
    )
</div></div>
```

_RepLevelEditPartial.cshtml

```
<div id="newGrid" class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6">
    @(Html
        .Grid(Model)
        .Build(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add(model => model.ReputationLevelID).Css("hidden");
            columns.Add(model => model.ReputationIsChecked).Encoded(false).RenderedAs(model => Html.CheckBoxFor(a => model.ReputationIsChecked));
            columns.Add(model => model.ReputationLevelName);
            columns.Add(model => model.ReputationLevelTier).Css("hidden");
        })
    )
</div></div>
```

Please help, if you can.  Point me in the correct direction.